# How to update personal cloned github?

Tags: python, github, git-clone

I recently downloaded an open-source project from github into my server using

```
$ git clone www.github.com/project_url
```

Then I added comments and descriptions inside the multiple files here and there. 
When I went to the github repository of the original project github page,
many of the files were updated. But I'm hesitating to clone again because I think it would just overwrite every local files to which I wrote many of the comments.

Is there anyway I can download up-to-date files in the github,
but leave the comments that I added not being removed at the same time?

Comment: Git pull and merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple strategies to go around this problem. A strategy is already explained. Another could be

1. Commit your changes `(git commit -am <message>)`
2. Do a git pull `(git pull -r)`
3. Resolve conflicts if any

Also, you can keep your changes separate in a separate branch. Here is what else can be done:

1. Create a separate branch in your local repository `(git checkout -b <branch-name>, eg. git checkout -b new-branch)`
2. commit changes in that new branch `(git commit -am <message>)`

Either you can merge now from your new branch to the old branch

1. `git checkout old-branch`; `git merge new-branch`.
2. resolve conflicts if any

OR

1. Raise a Pull Request after resolving any conflicts if any

Answer (score 1):

You can use git stash for this. This will store everything you changed locally. Then you pull the changes from the original repository and then with 'git stash pop' your local changes will come back.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Conflicts can come up and need to be resolved.